# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that parses an array of Episodes, that receives keyName that will be a key of Episode and a file path of an external file. The data will be set from file to the corresponding Episode:

```
const addPropertyByNameParsingFile_1 = (arrayToParse: Episode[], filePath: string, keyName: keyof Episode) => {
  const fileNamesArray = getFileNamesArray(filePath);

  arrayToParse.forEach(item => {
    fileNamesArray.forEach(fileName => {
      const [fileNamePosition] = fileName.split('_');
      if (fileNamePosition === item.helperPosition) {
        item[keyName] = fileName;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

It will be used like that:

```
addPropertyByNameParsingFile(episodesArr, videoFileNamesPath, 'fileName');

addPropertyByNameParsingFile(episodesArr, postersFileNamesPath, 'poster');
```

Now I want to use that function for arrays containing another type of objects.
Wanted to use Generics for that and refactored the function this way:

```
const addPropertyByNameParsingFile_2 =<T>(arrayToParse: T[], filePath: string, keyName: keyof T) => {
  const fileNamesArray = getFileNamesArray(filePath);

  arrayToParse.forEach(item => {
    fileNamesArray.forEach(fileName => {
      const [fileNamePosition] = fileName.split('_');
      if (fileNamePosition === item.helperPosition) {
        item[keyName] = fileName;
      }
    });
  });
```

But Typescript is not happy with `item[keyName]`,
**Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]**

How can I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: it's not `item[keyName]` per se that makes the problem, but as `item` is of generic type `T`, the compiler can't know what type `item[keyName]` would be (it could be a `string`, a `number`, a complex object, ...) so it won't allow to assign a `string` to it ..

Comment: Ok, understand. 
Just adding "as any" to the fileName solves the problem. But I am not very happy with the solution that include ```any```... it does not look right for me: 

```item[keyName] = fileName as any;```

Answer (score 0):

as @ derpirscher already commented, T is a generic type and the value of the type T[keyof T] could really be anything.

I have two suggestions on how to solve this:
First, don't modify the Object but return a Object based on it instead, and then use something like

```js
<T, U extends keyof T>(arrayToParse: T[], filePath: string, keyName: U) => (Record<U, string> & T)[]
```

as the type of your function.
This works because you define a new type based on the other type instead and then add your key to it and type it accordingly, as it should be, as a string.

Alternatively you could use something like

```js
<T extends string, U extends Record<T, string>>(arrayToParse: U[], filePath: string, keyName: T) => void
```

and let your function remain as it is. This should work as you check that your key has the type it needs to be, so the type of T[key] is known when you assign it.

Note: I haven't tested this myself, but off the top of my head that is roughly how it should work

Comment: const addPropertyByNameParsingFile = <T, U extends keyof T>(arrayToParse: T[], filePath: string, keyName: keyof T): (Record<U, string> & T)[] => {
  const fileNamesArray = getFileNamesArray(filePath);
  const resultArr = arrayToParse.map(item => {
    let clonedItem = { ...item } as Record<U, string> & T;
    fileNamesArray.forEach(fileName => {
      const [fileNamePosition] = fileName.split('_');
      if (fileNamePosition === item.helperPosition) {
        clonedItem[keyName] = fileName;
      }
    });
    return clonedItem;
  });
  return resultArr;
};

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(Record<U, string> & T)[keyof T]'

Comment: the second have the same problem
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'U[T]'